# replace /n to br

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

i'm loading a text with     `[WebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil ];` 
But in the XML they are using `/n` and not `<br />` how i can replace an `/n` to  `<br />` so i can get enters between the text?

**The text is now something like:**

> Lorem Ipsum /n dolar blabla

needs to be

> Lorem Ipsum Dolar blabla

```
 NSString *Display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Message];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />></head><body>%@</body></html> ",Display];  

    [WebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on your string:

```
myNSString = [myprevstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];
```

Comment: This is very close to correct. Here is the correct code [myprevstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"] - Correct method name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: and "\n" are the two errors in the above.